# Crispy forms ignores initial value for radio button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to conditionally set an initial value on a crispy forms InlineRadio field, and am getting ignored.

I set the `initial` value like so:

```
class CustomWizardForm3(ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset("",
            Div(ImageInlineRadios('sleeve_length'), css_class='span8 clearfix'),
            Div(
                CustomStyleDiv('armhole_edging_stitch', 'armhole_edging_height'),
                css_class="row-fluid")
        )
    ) 

    super(CustomWizardForm3, self).__init__(user, HELP_TEXT, *args, **kwargs)

    if self.instance.is_vest():
        self.fields['sleeve_length'].initial = DC.SLEEVE_VEST

  class Meta:
    model = IndividualDesign
    fields = ('armhole_edging_stitch', 'armhole_edging_height', 'sleeve_length',)
```

In the model, `sleeve_length` is declared as:

```
sleeve_length= models.CharField(
    max_length = 20,
    choices = DC.SLEEVE_LENGTH_CHOICES,
    null = True, 
    blank = True)
```

I've stepped through it in the debugger, and the `initial` attribute is set to what I expect.  But when the radio buttons are generated, nothing is checked.  What gives?  Crispy and/or Django Forms is driving me mad.

ETA:  ImageInlineRadios is a simple subclass of the standard crispy thing.

class ImageInlineRadios(InlineRadios):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.span_class = kwargs.pop('span_class', 2)
    super(ImageInlineRadios, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

template = 'radio_buttons.html'

def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack='bootstrap'):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    context.update({'inline_class': 'inline', 
                    'images': 'none', 
                    'span_class':self.span_class})
    return super(ImageInlineRadios, self).render(form, form_style, context)
```

In the radio_buttons.html template file, we have:

```
<input type="radio"
   {% if choice.0|stringformat:"s" == field.value|stringformat:"s" %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
```

Does crispy not set `field.value` from `initial`? That part looks to me like what's in the radioselect.html template that comes with crispy, but if there's something else I should test, I'd love to know what it is.

Comment: Argh.  "This is why initial values are only displayed for unbound forms. For bound forms, the HTML output will use the bound data." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/  Is there not any way to set a value on a field in a bound form?  form.data is immutable. This is ridiculous.